# How to pass a "Sequence" of type "T" as a parameter in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose I have a function that takes a sequence of "Person" objects. The sequence could be a simple array, or RealmSwift's Result, or List:

```
// A simple array
func someFunction(people: [Person]) {

}

// Result
func someFunction(people: Result<Person>) {

}

// List
func someFunction(people: List<Person>) {

}
```

Instead of having these 3 functions, I want to have only 1 function that takes a generic sequence of "Person" objects, something that looks like this:

```
func someFunction(people: Sequence<Person>) {

}
```

This way, I could pass an array, a Result or a List to the function and not have to worry that the types don't match. But obviously this is not allowed in Swift. How do I do that then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** Xcode 14.1 and Swift 5.7.1 were released today, and with these versions, you can now do this just with:

```
func someFunction(people: some Sequence<Person>) { ... }
```

Original answer is below.

--

You can do this with a where clause. Read about where clauses here:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID192

To answer your specific question, you can create a generic `Sequence` constraint and constrain its `Element` like so:

```
func someFunction<S: Sequence>(people: S) where S.Element == Person { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you. What if my function returns a generic sequence of type Person? How do I do that?

Comment: Oh I see, I tried `func someFunction<S: Sequence>() -> (S) where S.Element == Person` and it works! Thank you very much!